# How may I resize image data in the format of an Xamarin.Forms.Point array?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How may I resize image data in the format of an Xamarin.Forms.Point array to a defined height and width value?

Researching online, I found methods that resize image data in the format of a `byte[]` but none that resized image data in the format of an `Xamarin.Forms.Point` array. (Example: `Xamarin.Forms.Point[158]`)

Comment: I don't think there is probably any magic answer to this - you'll just have to write the code yourself.  There are probably established algorithms for transforming a set of x,y coordinates that you can use as a starting point.